# Как через API stackoverflow можно получить тело вопроса?

Tags: stackoverflow-api

`ID` вопроса: `68674674`.

Хочу получить сам вопрос. Но на мой запрос получаю:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "google-chrome-extension"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "account_id": 13465298,
        "reputation": 577,
        "user_id": 9715816,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bd794cb46005a234bd6e44397c8d403b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
        "display_name": "Charalamm",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/9715816/charalamm"
      },
      "is_answered": false,
      "view_count": 11,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "score": 0,
      "last_activity_date": 1628207842,
      "creation_date": 1628207842,
      "question_id": 68674674,
      "content_license": "CC BY-SA 4.0",
      "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68674674/chrome-extension-access-content-of-other-tab",
      "title": "Chrome extension access content of other tab"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9924
}
```

[Ссылка на запрос](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=68674674&filter=!*MZqiH2QKqSmBlHE&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Comment: А запрос-то сам какой?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=68674674&filter=!*MZqiH2QKqSmBlHE&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: добавь параметр `&filter=withbody`

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=1314781&filter=withbody&site=ru.stackoverflow&run=true